# one log for one bundle in servicemix

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I want to have a log file for every bundle. This is my configuration in servicemix:

```
log4j.appender.bpa=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
log4j.appender.bpa.key=app.name
log4j.appender.bpa.default=bpa
log4j.appender.bpa.appender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.bpa.appender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.bpa.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.bpa.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n 
log4j.appender.bpa.appender.file=${karaf.data}/log/${bundle.name}.log 
log4j.appender.bpa.appender.append=true 

log4j.category.com.apba.bpa=INFO, bpa
```

But the result shows log name org.apache.camel.camel-core.log instead the name of my bundle.

What's the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the configuration to sift based on bundle name or use the "MDC" feature when logging in your application and Camel routes.

Try adding this to config:

```
log4j.appender.sift.key=bundle.name
```

The catch with Camel routes, is that all the logs will be for the camel-core bundle and probably not what you are looking for. Best Practice to use MDC identifiers explicitly in your code and routes.

See JBO's full blog on it here: http://blog.nanthrax.net/2014/08/mdc-logging-with-apache-karaf-and-camel/